# Find all left cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

$H = \{(1,2), id \}$ - subgroup of $S_3$. Find all left cosets of the subgroup $H$ of $S_3$.

I know left cosets should exhaust $S_3$ and left coset looks like $ \{ \tau \cdot (1 2), \tau \cdot id \}$.

At first, i thought i need just evaluate all possible multiplications $ \{ \tau \cdot (1 2), \tau \cdot id \}$, where $\tau \in S_3$, but $\tau \notin H$. However, i'm assuming i don't need to take all possible multiplications, because $S_3$ will exhaust earlier.

The second concerning thing is that multiple evaluation of permutation multiplications is very exhaustive action and it's definitely not the right thing to do, so is there any special notation, which helps write down the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you don't *need* to take all of them as different $\tau_1, \tau_2 \in S$ may be in the same left coset and thus $\tau_1\in \tau_2 H$ and equivalently $\tau_2 \in \tau_1 H$. For example the cosets $(1,2)H$ is just $H$ as is $id H$.

Permutation multiplication can be annoying, but in this case, $S_3$ is small enough to do everything out by hand. Are you using two-line notation or cyclic notation? I find the latter works well in small cases like this.

See: [Permutation Notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_notations)

Comment: Yea, you are right. The problem for me was to find the point where i should stop. Now i finally realized that i should use the Lagrange's theorem to calculate amount of distinct cosets. For, example let's say Lagrange's theorem gave me 3, so at the moment when i get 3 different cosets i should stop.

Comment: Precisely! Further, you can know which elements not to try for forming new cosets if they are already in another one.